# Convert LDAP search results into CSV

Tags: ruby, csv, search, ldap, ldap-query

I'm currently working on a program that takes the results of an LDAP search and converts it into CSV. I've never worked with LDAP before, only SQL, and I find it a bit challenging.

I'm having trouble getting the LDAP data into a form that will translate well to CSV. I've been trying to use what I learned in SQL to help out, but it's proving to be a bit challenging.

Here's the LDAP server I'm working with.

## example.org

```
dn: dc=example,dc=org
objectClass: top
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
o: Example Inc.
dc: example

# admin, example.org
dn: cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org
objectClass: simpleSecurityObject
objectClass: organizationalRole
cn: admin
description: LDAP administrator
userPassword: mypassword

# people, example.org
dn: ou=people,dc=example,dc=org
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: people

# chris, people, example.org
dn: uid=jane,ou=people,dc=example,dc=org
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
cn: Chris
sn: smith
mail: chris@example.org
uid: chris
```

And here's the Ruby code I'm using to try to get the data.

```
ldap = Net::LDAP.new  :host => '127.0.0.1',
  :port => 1300,
  :auth => {
    :method => :simple,
    :username => 'cn=admin,dc=example,dc=org',
    :password => 'mypassword'
}
filter = Net::LDAP::Filter.eq( "cn", "Chris*")
treebase = "dc=example,dc=org"

ldap.search( :base => treebase, :filter => filter ) do |entry|
  CSV.open("mysearch.csv", "w") do |csv|
  puts "DN: #{entry.dn}"
  entry.each do |attribute, values|
    search_array.push(attribute)
    values.each do |value|
     csv << [attribute, values]
     data_array.push(values)
    end
    end
  end
end
```

When I try to load it up in a CSV, here's what I end up getting:
[image: wrong]

How can I get the headers to line up at the top of the page, not vertically? Any pointers/suggestions from anyone?

Answer (score 0):

The result set returned by default is a bit special: 
https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-net-ldap/Net/LDAP/Entry

I would add the attribute names In the first line of the new CSV file like this:

```
result_set = ldap.search( :base => treebase, :filter => filter )
CSV.open("mysearch.csv", "w") do |csv|
  csv << result_set.map { |entry| entry.attribute_names }
  result_set.each do |entry|
     csv << [entry.dn] # add what you need additionally to dn https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-net-ldap/Net/LDAP/Entry)
  end
end
```

P.S. Maybe you need to use result_set.first.attribute_names instead of the map line.

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't work, it says "keys" is an undefined method.

Comment: Yes, I was going to say that the class turned out to be "Net::LDAP::Entry"

Comment: Unfortunately, map isn't working either. This is a tricky one.

Comment: Try without a block. I will add the option to my answer.